# NimbleKit 1.9.8 xCode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

Im new to iOS development. When using NimbleKit 1.9.8 and xCode 4.2 and keep getting an error after selecting the path for the new project. The screen for selecting options is also blank. After clicking continue in the path selection screen when creating a new project, I get the error:

Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because NimbleKit 1.9.8 is not compatible with xCode 4.2.
Just use the SDK 4.2 with a older xCode Version or wait for an upgrade of NimbleKit.

Answer (score 0):

I have NimbleKit 1.9.8.1 working with XCode 4.2.1 without a hitch. I know it's lame, but I would try reinstalling NimbleKit then XCode. Good luck.